# How do I select a row based on a date

Tags: php, sql

I have row in which is string value from strtotime(), for example `1303448400`.

My table has following stucture:

```
id | date
```

And from my input I recive date in this format: `MM/DD/YY`.

How to create a query in SQL which will select id where date is greater than `11/11/13`?

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server or any other SQL ?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your date (11/11/13) to a timestamp before using it in a query, using mktime():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) as you said,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE > strtotime($yourDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $date=strtotime('11/11/13');
 SELECT * FROM TABLE db_date DATE > $date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it will work for you.

```
$date_1 = 11/11/13; // your date 
$date_2 = strtotime($date_1); //change it to strtotime
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE date DATE > '".$date_2."'"); //select id which is greater
```

Change the variables and rows to fit yours.